Give more weights to some input features for variational auto encoder
I made a variation auto encoder to augment data.
It is working fine, but I would like some columns in the augmented data to have more variations  than the others.
For example, I actually have this data generated:
100  16 2.6
105  16.6 2.7
110  16.7 2.8

You will tell me: it is normal, you don't have enough real input data in a big range for the second column around 105 value for the first column. That's true but my second column is important and here is what looks like my input data important :
100 16 2.5
110 20 3.5
120 30 3.7
130 40 4 
200 80 7 
.....

I would like give more weight to the second column to vary in a full  range of the real input data from 1 to 100, and have a result like this:
100 20  3
105 50  3.5
110 80  6
....

EDIT:
I tried it ... not really good :
class customLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(customLoss, self).__init__()
        self.mse_loss = nn.MSELoss(reduction="sum")
    
    def forward(self, x_recon, x, mu, logvar):
        loss_MSE = self.mse_loss(x_recon, x)
        #   Kullback-Leibler (KL) divergence
        loss_KLD = -0.5 * torch.sum(1. + logvar - mu.pow(2) - logvar.exp())
        # Variance penalty for feature 2
        variance_penalty = torch.mean(logvar[:, 2])  # Average logvar for feature 2

        loss_original = loss_MSE + loss_KLD - variance_penalty * 2.
        return loss_original


Perhaps you could add an additional penalty to the loss that incentivises higher variance for feature 2.
One way of doing this is to directly incorporate sigma_feature2 into the loss term, e.g. loss_total = loss_original + lambda * 1 / sigma_feature2**2, where sigma_feature2 is the the variance parameter of the latent representation for feature 2.
Alternatively, you could add an activation loss term that looks at the output activations for feature 2, and adds lambda * 1 / feature2_activations.var() to the loss term.
Both methods above obtain a measure of the degree of variance related to feature 2, and calculate 1 / variance before adding it to the loss. This means that when the variance is low, the loss increases and the model compensates by learning to increase the variance for that feature.
lambda would need to be tuned to achieve a balance between accurate and normally-distributed reconstructions for feature 2 (small lambda), whilst still getting your desired level of variance for that feature (larger lambda).

I am not sure I have coded it correctly, but it does not change the result.
This may be of KL term that will try to conform to fit with the distribution.

`
def forward(self, x_recon, x, mu, logvar):
loss_MSE = self.mse_loss(x_recon, x)
#   Kullback-Leibler (KL) divergence
loss_KLD = -0.5 * torch.sum(1. + logvar - mu.pow(2) - logvar.exp())
sigma = logvar[:,2] # feature 2 sigma
k = lambda_var * torch.sum(1. / sigma.pow(2))
loss_original = loss_MSE + loss_KLD + k
return loss_original

`

For k I'd try k = lambda_var * torch.sum( (logvar[:,2] / 2).exp() ). First thing would be to ensure the model works well/as expected when there is no k (set lambda_var=0). Then, try again with a small lambda_var (results shouldn't be drastically different). Then you can increase it and observe the effect it has...but I'd first ensure things are working ok without it.
